# Can't run sonar-scanner inside docker container: Permission denied

Tags: docker, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm trying to build a custom docker image with CI purposes (bitbucket pipelines). After build and test my code, I wish I could run some analysis with sonarqube.

On my custom image I tried to install sonar-scanner, so when in the container it will just be executed. However, inside the container (either on bitbucket or my local machine) it fails with this error:

```
/sonar-scanner-2.8/bin/sonar-scanner: 108: exec: : Permission denied
```

I already tried many different ways to set permissions and ownership on the scanner directory, but nothing has worked.

More surprisingly, even when running the container with the flash `--privileged=true` I still get the same error.

What am I missing on docker basics?

This is my last version of the Dockerfile:

```
# Pull base image.
FROM node:6

LABEL maintainer "Gabriel Araujo <contact@gbiel.com>"

ENV SONAR_SCANNER_VERSION 2.8
ENV SONAR_SCANNER_HOME /home/sonar-scanner-${SONAR_SCANNER_VERSION}
ENV SONAR_SCANNER_PACKAGE sonar-scanner-${SONAR_SCANNER_VERSION}.zip
ENV SONAR_RUNNER_HOME ${SONAR_SCANNER_HOME}
ENV PATH $PATH:${SONAR_SCANNER_HOME}/bin
ENV WORKDIR /home/workspace

# Define working directory.
WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get -yqq update && \
    apt-get -yqq --no-install-recommends install git bzip2 curl unzip && \
    npm install -g gulp bower && \
    npm cache clean && \
    apt-get -yqq autoremove && \
    apt-get -yqq clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Allow root for bower
RUN echo '{ "allow_root": true }' > /root/.bowerrc

# Download sonar
RUN curl --insecure -OL https://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/${SONAR_SCANNER_PACKAGE} && \
  unzip ${SONAR_SCANNER_PACKAGE} -d /home && \
  rm ${SONAR_SCANNER_PACKAGE}

RUN addgroup sonar && \
  useradd -s /usr/sbin/nologin -d ${SONAR_SCANNER_HOME} -g sonar sonar && \
  chown -R sonar:sonar ${SONAR_SCANNER_HOME} && \
  chown -R sonar:sonar ${WORKDIR}

USER sonar
```

Comment: what is your docker run command?

Comment: I have provided a tested and working example in my answer. If you found this useful please upvote and accept my answer.

Comment: I accepted you answer. As you figured out, it was requiring Java 8, indeed. However, the error message wasn't helping for pointed something about permissions. Anyway, thank you for you help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java 8 Needs to be installed first, since sonar scanner requires it. I have added it to your Dockerfile. Needs to be installed from jessie backports.

**You should probably merge my additions to your existing `Install dependencies` section**

```
# Pull base image.
FROM node:6

LABEL maintainer "Gabriel Araujo <contact@gbiel.com>"

ENV SONAR_SCANNER_VERSION 2.8
ENV SONAR_SCANNER_HOME /home/sonar-scanner-${SONAR_SCANNER_VERSION}
ENV SONAR_SCANNER_PACKAGE sonar-scanner-${SONAR_SCANNER_VERSION}.zip
ENV SONAR_RUNNER_HOME ${SONAR_SCANNER_HOME}
ENV PATH $PATH:${SONAR_SCANNER_HOME}/bin
ENV WORKDIR /home/workspace

# Define working directory.
WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}

# Install OpenJDK 8
RUN echo 'deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list && \
     apt-get update && \
     apt-get install -y -t jessie-backports openjdk-8-jre-headless ca-certificates-java

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get -yqq update && \
    apt-get -yqq --no-install-recommends install git bzip2 curl unzip && \
    npm install -g gulp bower && \
    npm cache clean && \
    apt-get -yqq autoremove && \
    apt-get -yqq clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Allow root for bower
RUN echo '{ "allow_root": true }' > /root/.bowerrc

# Download sonar
RUN curl --insecure -OL https://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/${SONAR_SCANNER_PACKAGE} && \
  unzip ${SONAR_SCANNER_PACKAGE} -d /home && \
  rm ${SONAR_SCANNER_PACKAGE}

RUN addgroup sonar && \
  useradd -s /usr/sbin/nologin -d ${SONAR_SCANNER_HOME} -g sonar sonar && \
  chown -R sonar:sonar ${SONAR_SCANNER_HOME} && \
  chown -R sonar:sonar ${WORKDIR}

USER sonar
```

Now it should work:

```
docker build -t sonar-test .
docker run -it --rm sonar-test /home/sonar-scanner-2.8/bin/sonar-scanner --help
INFO: 
INFO: usage: sonar-scanner [options]
INFO: 
INFO: Options:
INFO:  -D,--define <arg>     Define property
INFO:  -h,--help             Display help information
INFO:  -v,--version          Display version information
INFO:  -X,--debug            Produce execution debug output
INFO:  -i,--interactive      Run interactively
```